# why process give null inputstream in test runner class?

Tags: android, process, test-project

In my android test project, I simply read the `logcat` using `adb command`

like,

```
public StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
    public String line="";
    public String temp="";

public void testSolo() throws Exception {

             String baseCommand = "logcat -v time";
            baseCommand += " ActivityManager:I "; // Info for my app
            baseCommand += " *:S "; // Silence others

            try {
                  Process logReaderProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(baseCommand);
                  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(logReaderProcess.getInputStream()));

                   while ((line =bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            log.append(line); // here readLine() returns null
                          }

            }
            catch (IOException e1) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                      e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

 }
```

but, here in `string line` I always get **null value**,

while the same thing always run in the android `activity's onCreate()` .
I don't understand why this happen?

Same thing runs in activity class and not in the android test project.

I also add use -permission for `READ_LOGS`  and  `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in test project's
`manifest.xml` file.

Is there anybody knows how it works or what happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you want the output stream?

Comment: Do you mean you're not managing to log anything? I strongly suggest that you put a logging statement in your exception handler...

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Thanks for your reply, I am getting the values from the logcat. using the above command, now when the same things If I put in android activity it gives me whole values from logcat Tag by ActivityManager and the same thing returns null values in android test project. I don't understand what happen.

Comment: @user370305: Perhaps logcat simply doesn't work in test projects? Perhaps there are other ways of getting log information in tests?

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I don't know whether other ways are available or not, I also noticed the things happen only for logcat. But we can print the log message from the test project then why we can't access for read?

Comment: @user370305: I don't know - but I'd expect there to be something about diagnostics in the documentation...

Comment: @Jon Skeet - ok, Thanks for your valuable time given to me. Now, I am try different things to get the log in the test project. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

to your manifest.

Comment: read my question properly I mentioned, I added READ_LOGS permission.

Answer (score -1):

```
String []baseCommand = new String[]{"logcat", "-v","time"}; 
Process logReaderProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(baseCommand);
```

try this out